# MoPub showing attempts and but not displaying ads from Millennial Media

Tags: android, mopub, millennial-media

I've ensured proguard is set correctly and have kind of kept all classes using :

```
-keep class com.millennialmedia.android.** {*;}
-keep class com.millennialmedia.google.** {*;}
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with entering the parameters. Can someone confirm if my understanding is correct or if something needs to be changed?

When adding the millennial media network on mopub site:

**Publisher Alias, Site Alias, and Spot Alias**

***Publisher Alias*** - I've tried using the email used to login to mmedia.com as well as the company name. Which one should it be? Or is it something altogether different ?

***Site Alias*** - I've entered the App Name that i wrote when creating ad units in mmedia.com - is this correct?

***Spot Alias*** - I entered the ID for each position created on mmedia. - is this correct?

MoPub is really confusing. The documentation did not help much. Any inputs in helping resolve this will be great. Thanks

Also, I get a feel that mopub is completely ignoring millennial media network because i see nothing on logcat as well related to this network.

UPDATE:

I'm getting this error once in a while:

===========================================================

```
12-01 06:52:07.490: E/MMSDK-MMSDK(29479): Unrecoverable error connecting to Google Play services (e.g.,the old version of the service doesnt support getting AdvertisingId: java.io.IOException: Connection failure
12-01 06:52:07.490: E/MMSDK-MMSDK(29479):   at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.i(Unknown Source)
12-01 06:52:07.490: E/MMSDK-MMSDK(29479):   at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.start(Unknown Source)
12-01 06:52:07.490: E/MMSDK-MMSDK(29479):   at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
12-01 06:52:07.490: E/MMSDK-MMSDK(29479):   at com.millennialmedia.android.MMSDK.getAdvertisingInfo(MMSDK.java:1034)
12-01 06:52:07.490: E/MMSDK-MMSDK(29479):   at com.millennialmedia.android.MMSDK.insertUrlCommonValues(MMSDK.java:891)
12-01 06:52:07.490: E/MMSDK-MMSDK(29479):   at com.millennialmedia.android.HandShake$1.run(HandShake.java:333)
12-01 06:52:07.490: E/MMSDK-MMSDK(29479):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-01 06:52:07.490: E/MMSDK-MMSDK(29479):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-01 06:52:07.490: E/MMSDK-MMSDK(29479):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself. The problem was that I'd selected the legacy Millennial Media when seeing up the network. Removed it and switched to the other millennial media. Working fine now.